# Graphviz: how to arrange nodes with circo layout

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to draw a graph with circle topology.

Here is what I'm expecting to see:
[image]

Here is my gv file:

```
digraph g1 {
    layout="circo";
    node [shape = doublecircle]; N4 N6;
    node [shape = circle];
    N0 -> N1 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N1 -> N2 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N2 -> N3 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N3 -> N4 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N4 -> N5 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N5 -> N6 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N6 -> N0 [ label = "{1,0}"];

    N0 -> N4 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N1 -> N5 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N2 -> N6 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N3 -> N0 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N4 -> N1 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N5 -> N2 [ label = "{1,0}"];
    N6 -> N3 [ label = "{1,0}"];    
}
```

And here is an output image for graph above:
[image]

How can I arrange nodes in graphviz to make it look like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBSco.png)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the goal is to have a graph which respects the order of the nodes, it's not that simple. You could [calculate the position of the nodes with an external script and render it with neato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242949/graphviz-circular-layout-while-preserving-node-order).

Or you could first layout the nodes with the edges which determine the correct order of the nodes only:

```
digraph g1 {
    node [shape = doublecircle]; N4 N6;
    node [shape = circle];
    edge[label="{1,0}"];
    N0 -> N1 -> N2 -> N3 -> N4 -> N5 -> N6 -> N0;
}
```

with:

```
circo graph.gv > tempgraph.gv
```

Then add the remaining edges to `tempgraph.gv` - just copy-paste the following before the closing `}`:

```
N0 -> N4 [ label = "{1,0}"];
N1 -> N5 [ label = "{1,0}"];
N2 -> N6 [ label = "{1,0}"];
N3 -> N0 [ label = "{1,0}"];
N4 -> N1 [ label = "{1,0}"];
N5 -> N2 [ label = "{1,0}"];
N6 -> N3 [ label = "{1,0}"];
```

And render it with `neato` and the `-n` option:

```
neato -n tempgraph.gv -Tpng -O
```

You may want to fine-tune the position of the labels:

[image: circo layout]

Comment: Thanks the `circo` command was what I wanted but I was only trying `dot` and `neato` now I see why I could not get a circular layout!