# How can I draw a circular graph with a node inside, using graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz

I want to produce a circular graph with one (and possibly several others...) in the middle of the circle.
As an example, consider this simple 7-nodes undirected graph:

```
graph g1 {

0--1;
0--2;
0--3;
0--4;
0--5;
0--6;


1--2--3--4--5--6--1;
}
```

I would like something like this (did online with [csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/](https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/):
[image]

The [Graphviz circo](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/circo/) engine does a good job putting all the nodes in a circular layout, but I want the node 0 to be in the middle.

I read on its page that [the attribute root](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/root/) can be used to specify which one is in the middle:

> The center of the layout will be the root of the generated spanning tree.
> As a graph attribute, this gives the name of the node.
> As a node attribute, it specifies that the node should be used as a central node.

As I understand it, this attribute can be used either as a global graph attribute, either as a "node" attribute. So I tried adding:

```
0[root=true];
```

at the beginning, to tell him that the node 0 is the root one. No change.

I also tried `graph [root=0];`, no success (see [live demo here](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#graph%20g1%20%7B%0Alayout%3D%22circo%22%3B%0A%0A%23graph%20%5Broot%3D0%5D%3B%0A0%5Broot%3Dtrue%5D%3B%0A%0A%0A0--1%3B%0A0--2%3B%0A0--3%3B%0A0--4%3B%0A0--5%3B%0A0--6%3B%0A%0A%0A1--2--3--4--5--6--1%3B%0A%7D%0A)). How can I achieve this?

[Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72537303/193789) suggest adding a "hidden" node, but I can't do that because the dot file is used both to produce a rendering and as data input for something else.

**Second question**: would it be possible to have a "cluster" of several nodes in the middle of the circle, using that technique? Or does the "root" attribute need to be assigned to a single node?

**Edit** For example, something like this, with 3 nodes inside the circular layout.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**twopi** layout is pretty much "take it or leave it".
The following gets pretty close, but starts getting fiddley with **weight** attributes (different than **weight** for the other engines).
If you want more control, here is a link to a radial layout preprocessor for **Graphviz** https://gist.github.com/steveroush/60d9a850a545ec4e02b0482c7bac3ad5

```
graph g1 {
  root="X"  // added - invisible root
  X [shape=point style=invis]
  ranksep=".5:2"  // inches
  { edge [style=invis]
    X -- {0 6 7}
  }
  0 -- {6 7}
  6 -- 7

  0 -- {2 3}
  6 -- {4 5}
  7 -- {1 }
  7 -- {2 } [style=invis]

  edge[weight=0]  // similar to constraint=false for dot
  0 -- 4
  6 -- 1

  edge[weight=1]  
  1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 1
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that very interesting! And I'll have a look to your sh script. I'll accept this one, although in my case I cannot add an invisible node.

Answer (score 2):

Use **twopi** (https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/twopi/) instead of **circo**.
Note that the node placement (starting point, direction, and sequence) seems to be out of our control (though OK to my eye).

Please say more or show an example of **Question #2** (sketch would be fine)

```
graph g1 {
root="0"

0--1;
0--2;
0--3;
0--4;
0--5;
0--6;
1--2--3--4--5--6--1;
}
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: Ah, great, thanks, I clearly misunderstood how to use the "root" attribute. I'll edit question to clarify the second point.

Comment: I tried with 2 root nodes, went fine, but fails with 3.